# having problem with multiple else and brackets

Tags: discord.js

I am new to this, am I doing something wrong? I get problems on all the else.

```
Statement expected on the else on line 104, line 122.
Declaration or statement expected on the else on line 129 and the case on line 134.
';' expected on line 133 and 138.
```

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'secret';
bot.login(token);


const PREFIX = '!';
const sender = ';;ruling';
let msg = 'msg.content'

bot.on('error', () =>{
console.log('Error');
})

bot.on('ready', () =>{
console.log('POGO HUDDINGE bot is back online!');
})

bot.on('message', msg=>{
if(msg.content === "Hej"){
    msg.reply('Hejsan');
}
let args  = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");



switch(args[0]){
    case 'gymlista':
        const embed0 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            embed0.setTitle('Gymlista')
            embed0.setColor('#0099ff')
            embed0.setURL('')
            embed0.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
            embed0.setDescription('En karta samt lista över alla gym i Huddinges chattar. Klicka på     länken ovan!')
            embed0.setThumbnail('')
            embed0.setTimestamp('')
            embed0.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
            msg.channel.send(embed0);
        break;
    case 'hjälp':
        const embedh = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            embedh.setTitle('Allmänt')
            embedh.setColor('#0099ff')
            embedh.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
            embedh.setDescription('POGO HUDDINGE BOT är skapad och programmerad av @Pushos och är avsedd till Pokémon Go Huddinges discord server. Kontakta gärna mig om du har några frågor eller funderingar. :blush:')
            embedh.setThumbnail('')
            embedh.setTimestamp('')
            embedh.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
            embedh.addField('Version', 'v. 1.0 5');
            embedh.addField('Datum skapad', '26/12 -2019')
            embedh.addField('Skapad av', '@Pushos')
            embedh.addField('Prefix', '!')
            embedh.addField('Fungerar i (kanal)', '#botcommands')
            msg.channel.send(embedh);
        const embedh2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            embedh2.setTitle('Commands')
            embedh2.setColor('#0099ff')
            embedh2.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
            embedh2.setDescription('Nedan kommer en lista över alla commands som går att använda med denna bot. Alla commands skrivs i kanalen #botcommands med ett ! innan kommandot.')
            embedh2.setThumbnail('')
            embedh2.setTimestamp('')
            embedh2.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över alla commands, samt information.', '');
            embedh2.addField('!hittagym <gymnamn>', 'Tar upp vägbeskrivning över gymmet du letar efter.');
            embedh2.addField('!gymlista', 'Karta samt lista över alla gym i Huddinges chattar.')
            msg.channel.send(embedh2);
        break;
    case 'hittagym':
        if(args[1] === 'Asmunds'){
            if(args[2] === 'häst'){
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            embed.setTitle('Asmunds häst')
            embed.setColor('#0099ff')
            embed.setURL('')
            embed.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
            embed.setDescription('**EX Raid Gym**')
            embed.setThumbnail('')
            embed.setTimestamp('')
            embed.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
            embed.addField('Nära:', 'Fullersta gårdsväg 18');
            embed.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23911, 17.97408')
            embed.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
            msg.channel.send(embed);
        }
        }
        else {
            if(args[1] === 'Sjödalsparkens'){
                if(args[2] === 'Utomhusscen'){
                const embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                embed2.setTitle('Sjödalsparkens Utomhusscen')
                embed2.setColor('#0099ff')
                embed2.setURL('')
                embed2.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                embed2.setDescription('**Ex Raid Gym**')
                embed2.setThumbnail('')
                embed2.setTimestamp('')
                embed2.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                embed2.addField('Nära:', 'Klockarvägen 2');
                embed2.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23698, 17.98447')
                embed2.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                msg.channel.send(embed2);
        }
        }
        }else {
            if(args[1] === 'Rådsparkens'){
                if(args[2] === 'Utegym'){
                const embed3 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                embed3.setTitle('Rådsparkens Utegym')
                embed3.setColor('#0099ff')
                embed3.setURL('')
                embed3.setAuthor('POGO Huddinge', '')
                embed3.setDescription('**Ex Raid Gym**')
                embed3.setThumbnail('')
                embed3.setTimestamp('')
                embed3.setFooter('!hjälp för en lista över fler commands.', '');
                embed3.addField('Nära:', 'Kommunalvägen 27A');
                embed3.addField('Koordinater:', '59.23994, 17.98693')
                embed3.addField('Centrala Huddinge', '#centrala_huddinge')
                msg.channel.send(embed3);
            }
            }
            }else {
            if(args[1] === 'Stenfontän3'){



            }
            }
            }else {
            if(args[1] === 'Stenfontän4'){
            }
            }
            break;
    case 'clear':
        if(!args[1]) return msg.reply('Error please define second arg')
        msg.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
        break;
    }
    }
bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I noticed that you were not doing your if else statements correctly.

What you're doing:

```
if (something){something} else{if(something){something}} else {if(something){something} etc.
```

What you should be doing:

```
if (something){something} else if (something){something} else if(something){something} else{something}
```

not sure if that was the only reason but try that atleast